# - SwiftUI - Migration from SwiftData to Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ipados, swift-data

I'm working on a cross-platform `iOS/iPadOS/MacOS` app

The application uses **SwiftData** to persistently save user data.

Now my question may seem stupid but I'm trying to understand if there is a way to migrate **(in the future)** user data from `SwiftData` to `Firebase`.

I'm looking online but I couldn't find anything clear about it.

Some senior developers will surely be able to answer this question and perhaps provide information to understand better.

This question arose because I would like to provide the user who purchases the pro version with the possibility of saving all the data stored with `SwiftData` on `Firebase` so that they can always have them available even if they delete the app from the device only if it is a premium user

I apologize immediately if this question may seem stupid or meaningless and I will be grateful to anyone who can help me understand how to solve this question

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? If you are looking for some out-of-the-box solution I am pretty sure none exists and if you’re looking for a custom solution the question is too vague so the only valid answer is: yes it is possible.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson So there would be a possibility but it's very complex, right? Would you recommend a total data migration from swiftData to Firebase or the use of both? I don't know if my idea of ​​providing the user who decides to become pro with the possibility of saving the data entered into the app on a server is good or would only lead to many problems. What would you recommend?

Comment: Sure it would be possible. If the app isn't released to the App Store then there's no issues. If it is or will be, then for a fresh install there's no issues, but the Firebase version of your would would need to detect its running for the first time and has been installed over an existing older version of the app and then you'd need to implement a one time migration of any existing data from SwiftData to Firebase

Comment: This question may be a bit off topic for SO and closed as it's too broad. In a nutshell, SwiftData and Firebase are unrelated platforms and have very little similarity in their implementation and are really for different uses. SwiftData is Offline first, single user with iCloud sync. Firebase is Online first sync'd database well suited for multi-user environments with massive datasets that's highly scaleable. You should evaluate your use case; it this a multi-user app? Does it need to be Offline first or Online? Does the app need to react to multiple users updating or changing data?

Comment: more unhelpful comments. shameful. This question is a very good question that will be very relevant very soon, as SwiftData is a new thing in the latest version of Xcode and Swift and Firebase is already well established, so being able to migrate from one to the other will be a very useful thing to be able to know how to do. Admins once again show they are not about helping people but about closing stuff down. smh